# How to Ignore Third Party Component css files while using babel-plugin-react-css-modules

Tags: react-css-modules, babel-plugin

I have this situation where in one of my Component **JSX** file (For Eg. **List.jsx**) is importing the styles as follows :

```
import styles from "./css/list.rcss"; 
import "fixed-data-table.css"; 
import "./css/fixed-data-table.css";
```

- 1st import, the .rcss is our local `css` files where we use the `react-css-modules` rules
- 2nd import belongs to the FixedDataTable Component (Third Party)
- 3rd import is Global `css` file that uses standard `css` rules

This works well with **react-css-modules** but **babel-plugin-react-css-modules** throws the error because we are importing two anonymous imports.

Is there a work around or fix for this?

Comment: Does it fix the problem if you use a named import?